# what is -> in c++ in a function declaration

Tags: c++, syntax, c++11, decltype

In the Wikipedia article on `decltype` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype I came across this example:

```
int& foo(int& i);
float foo(float& f);

template <class T> auto transparent_forwarder(T& t) −> decltype(foo(t)) {
  return foo(t);
}
```

Though I understood the motive behind this function, I didnot understand the syntax it uses and specifically the `->` in the declaration. What is -> and how is it interpreted?

**EDIT 1**

Based on the above: What is wrong here?

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto sum(T1 v1, T2 v2) -> decltype(v1 + v2) {
    return v1 + v2;
}
```

The error is:

```
error: expected type-specifier before ‘decltype’
error: expected initializer before ‘decltype
```

**Answer to EDIT 1:**

OOPS! I forgot to use `-std=c++11` compiler option in g++.

**EDIT 2**

Based on the below answer. I have a related question: Look at the declaration below:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
decltype(*(T1 *) nullptr + *(T2 *) nullptr) sum2(T1 v1, T2 v2);
```

It is using `decltype` without the need for `->` in the function declaration. So Why do we need `->`

Comment: http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#suffix-return

Comment: To all those who voted for a close of this question. This question is different from linked question after my edits. Have a look again.

Comment: @footy: If you have a new question, ask a new question. SO is a Q&A site, not a threaded discussion site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This uses *trailing return type* notation. This:

```
auto f() -> T { ... }
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
T f() { ... }
```

The advantage is that with a trailing return type notation you can express the type of a function based on expressions that involve the arguments, which is not possible with the classical notation. For instance, this would be illegal:

```
    template <class T>
    decltype(foo(t)) transparent_forwarder(T& t) {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//  Error! "t" is not in scope here...

        return foo(t);
    }
```

Concerning your edit:

> Based on the above: What is wrong here?
>
> ```
> template <typename T1, typename T2>
> auto sum(T1 v1, T2 v2) -> decltype(v1 + v2) {
>     return v1 + v2;
> }
> ```

Nothing.

Concerning your second edit:

> [...] It is using decltype without the need for -> in the function declaration. So Why do we need ->

In this case you don't *need* it. However, the notation that does use trailing return type is much clearer, so one may prefer it to make the code easier to understand.

Comment: I added the actual error message.

Comment: @footy: What is your compiler?

Comment: .. Ahh I see now.. I forgot to use the `-std=c++11` option in g++

Comment: @footy: Thought so ;) Well, now you can play with it a bit

Comment: @footy: This is not the correct way of using SO though :) If you have new questions, ask new questions rather than editing questions that are already answered, otherwise I will have to keep asking further and further questions in the hope you will eventually accept my answer ;)

Comment: I will star a new question!

Comment: @footy: OK, but in the meanwhile I answered your second edit :D

Comment: THANKS! Ok I put it back up.. Wont do for further questions :P

Comment: @footy: lol, all right